# Apply :target to HTML elements with different ID

Tags: html, css

I have an overlay that shows a dismiss-able message when a page opens.

currently the content is loaded at the background, making my page scrollable. and on a browser i tested, opera mini, the content is shown at the background. i think it doesn't support transparency.

anyway, i decided to hide the content in the background until the message is dismissed instead of having a transparent layer to cover the content :

Here is my stripped css :

```
#Overlay { 
     width: 500px;   max-width:85%;
     margin:0 auto;     
     position:relative;     
     z-index:10;    
     display:block;     
     background-color:#363b59; }

#Overlay:target { display:none;}

#content { display:none;}
```

My Html

```
<div id="Overlay">
     <p>overlay content</p>
     <a href="#Overlay">cancel</a>
</div> 

<div id="content">
     <p>content goes here</p>
</div>
```

so , my question is : Is it possible to use the same  `#Overlay:target` that i use to hide the overlay to show the content. or is there a better way ?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page? It would help

Comment: ID's have to be unique. put the style in a class and use the class across the elements you want to hide.

Comment: @igorCarmagna currently my page is offline, will send you a link in a min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `div`s are siblings, you could use the general sibling selector `~`. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

***Snippet:***

```css
#Overlay { 
     width: 500px;   max-width:85%;
     margin:0 auto;     
     position:relative;     
     z-index:10;    
     display:block;     
     background-color:#363b59; 
}
#Overlay, #Overlay a { color: #fff; }
#Overlay:target { display:none;}

#Overlay ~ #content { display:none;}
#Overlay:target ~ #content { display:block;}
```

```html
<div id="Overlay">
     <p>overlay content</p>
     <a href="#Overlay">cancel</a>
</div> 

<div id="content">
     <p>content goes here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Jquery show() and hide() methods.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_show.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_hide.asp

If you want to make the content div visible and hide the overlay div

```
$("show_content_button").click(function(){ 
  $("#overlay").hide();
  $("#content").show();
});
```

If you want to make the overlay div visible again, and hide the content div.

```
$("show_overlay_button").click(function(){ 
  $("#overlay").show();
  $("#content").hide();
});
```

Anyway, if you'd like to do things even better I would recommend to implement bootstrap modals.
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Installing jQuery or a library in general just to achieve one thing, which you can do with CSS is not encouraged at all.

Comment: True if you consider this specific functionality, but I think that in a website project Jquery will probably be needed at some point. Anyway, abhitalks solution is more correct in this context.